# Redux not geting updated soon after button click-Redux, Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, redux

Not able to get value immediately after clicking button.

If i click my button i should be able to show my values.

if i check my redux state sometimes it get value n sometimes value will not be updated.

sometimes it get updated and shows values also.

Redux code

```
  case types.SHOW_WIDGETDATA_STORYBOARDS: {
  const newBoardList = state.boardList.map((item) => {
    if (item.boardId === action.selectedBoardId) {
      return {
        ...item,
        modifiedAt: Date.now(),
        widgetList: [...action.payload.selectedBoardData.widgetList],
      };
    }
    return item;
  });
  return { ...state, boardList: [...newBoardList] };
}
```